# Adding function to Helpers list in ArcGIS Pro Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.8 and would like to add a Function to the Helpers list in the Field Calculator.

Is this possible?

[image: Helper Function ArcGIS Pro FC]

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no you cannot alter what is offered up when you click on the helpers filter. You can however add your own function if you have pre-built it and saved it as a *calculate field expression* file

[image: buttons]